# Code Implementation: Hamcrest Matcher Interface and BaseMatcher abstract class

Tags: spring, interface, abstract-class, hamcrest

i have come across these comments in library of hamcrest matcher interface.

It is coded by Stevefreeman and Nat Pryce

---

Matcher implementations should **NOT directly implement this interface**.
 * Instead, **extend** the {@link BaseMatcher} abstract class,
 * which will ensure that the Matcher API can grow to support
 * new features and remain compatible with all Matcher implementations.

---

What advantage would a abstract class i.e BaseMatcher implementing the matcher interface provide over  the specialized class directly implementing matcher. If someone can explain with an example would help . i want to understand best practices for doing framework style code so I am curious to know when should one follow this pattern as i see similar style in Spring as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the Hamcrest designers decide to add a new method in the Matcher interface.

All the classes implementing Matcher directly wouldn't compile anymore.

But if they instead extend an abstract BaseMatcher class, the designers can add a default implementation of the new method in BaseMatcher, and all the existing subclasses would still compile.

Note that since Java 8, they could also add a default implementation directly in the interface. But Hamcrest was created long before Java 8.

Comment: thanks a lot i can see that the matcher, basematcher are in org.hamcrest but specific implementations are in *.* core package does that also help in anyway.

Comment: No. It's just where they decided to put the classes.